# netbeans project doesn't start web server

Tags: javascript, html, http, netbeans, webserver

I have 2 HTML5 projects.
One runs on http://localhost:8383 when I click on run.
The other runs on file:/// and (correctly) shows a "Cross origin request" error when loading a json file.

Both projects are relatively simple html+css+vanilla javascript projects.
I compared both projects carefully. Specifically, I compared the project properties. "Sources", "JavaScript" and "Run" appear to be identical. Both projects are set to "With Netbeans Connector", "Chrome", but I tested both with the embedded Webkit Browser as well.

Whatever I try, when I click on "Run", one projects starts as http://, as it should, the other insists to start as "file:///".

Does anyone have an idea where I should look?

EDIT:
Things I tried:

- Triple-checking Run configuration settings
- Restarting Netbeans
- Starting one project first, then the other
- Testing both projects with Chrome and the embedded Webkit browser

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Web Server for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?utm_source=gmail) is pretty cool for running small file sites.

Comment: Thanks, very nice idea. However, as one project is working fine, I'm sure it's a configuration problem somewhere in netbeans, and I'm curious what that could be. But I'll keep that extension in mind :)

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue and solved it. I created an HTML5 project using an Oracle JET template.
The issue is with the template which is being used while creating the project. Re-created the project by attaching a different template (older version of oracle jet library) and also created another without attaching any template and it works successfully.
It looks like some compatibility issue between netbeans and the attached template!

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to create a new project and copy all source files over.
Now the play button calls the web service.